# Easy way to store multiple data in Python 3

Tags: python, database

I am pretty new to Python, and so far I haven't stumbled upon any problems, until now.
I need a data structure that allows me to store multi dimensional data.
For example, I need my IRC bot to store all users and modes on a channel.
So it would look something like this:

```
[Name][Users][Nicklist][Modes][Topic][etc]
[#Home][50]['Nick1', 'Nick2', 'Nick3', 'etc'][+nt][topic here][more info]
[#Otherchan][10]['Nick1', 'Nick2', 'Nick3', 'etc'][+][topic][more info]
```

and I need to recall and edit the information via the channel name.
I been looking into lists and arrays but I have not found a convenient way to accomplish this.

If there is an even better way for this, that'd be great too.
I hope I'm explaining myself well.

Comment: Dictionaries, e.g. `{'name': '#Home', 'users': 50, ...}`?  Or `collections.namedtuple`.

Comment: Your data structure is rather unclear. Can dicts help you here? Possibly a dict that has a list or tuple as its values. Otherwise, you may have to go a step further and see if something like [Numpys structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) or [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) can suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the `dict` object.

```
d = {}
d['#Home'] = {}
d['#Home']['Users'] = 50
d['#Home']['Nicklist'] = ['Nick 1', 'Nick 2']
```

and so on

You can retrieve the values just like an array

```
print d['#Home']['Users']
50
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do what I want! Easy and simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

dictionaries (mutable):

```
test = {'data_name': data_value, 'data_name_2', data_value_2}
```

Lists (mutable):

```
test = ['a', 1, 2, [1, 2, 3], (1, 2)]
```

Tuples (immutable - cannot be modified or appended to afterwards):

```
test = (1, 2, 3, [5, 6, 7], 'a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a dictionary, which maps keys and values to each other. The syntax would be something like this:

```
d = {}
d['#Home'] = 50
d['Nicklist'] = ['Nick1', 'Nick2','Nick3','etc']
```

Also note for dicts, the keys and values can essentially be any object (as long as the keys are unique), and dicts  can be embedded within dicts, for example:

```
d= {}
d['#Home'] = {} #made a dict for the '#Home' key
d['#Home']['Nicklist'] = ['Nick1', 'Nick2','Nick3','etc']
```